# Drupal: remote development with Eclipse

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

What's the best solution to develop Drupal remotely on a development server, using Eclipse ?

I found this: http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/

Is this the best way to do it ? And above all, am I going to have some limitations ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have access via FTP you have two options.

You can set up a connection to the server using [remove system explorer](http://tmober.blogspot.com/2006/11/remote-system-explorer-10-is-released.html). When you set up a new project use the generic new project option and there you should have an option to choose which file system to use.

This will mean that you work directly on the server, be warned this can be slow sometimes, using FTP is slower than most other methods of connecting to a remote system.

The other option is to work locally and deploy to your server when you whish to test something. You can use the 'export' feature for this.

Comment: is "remove system explorer" a tool for eclipse, or what ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes SSH / SFTP is a better solution than Samba. SSH is likely to be activated on most servers an can be mounted into the local file system.

Comment: so I should point to a remote project from eclispe using ssh/sftp ? I don't need to install any additional plugin ? Is there any way to do it with ftp protocol ? I usually only have ftp access to the servers. thanks

Comment: there is Linux Userland Filesystem (LUFS): http://sourceforge.net/projects/lufs/ 
 
which enables you to mount different remote sources (as FTP). There seem to be solutions for Windows as well (just search google :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use samba on the machine. Point your project at it.

Comment: uhm, let's say I have not access to the configuration remote hosting service, and I cannot enable samba. I can still work on my remote drupal project with Eclipse ? (I only have ftp access usually :( )